# Can't get user chat message in ChatScreen flutter

Tags: flutter

I built a chat APP.
I have 2 kind of user to be used as "provisonal User" in model.
i defined a model class for currentUser

```
class User {
  final int id;
  final String firstName;
  final String lastName;
  final String nickName;
  final String email;
  final String imageProfile;

  const User(
      {this.id,
      this.firstName,
      this.lastName,
      this.nickName,
      this.email,
      this.imageProfile});
}

final User currentUser = User(
  id: 1,
  firstName: 'Stefano',
  lastName: 'Ambrogi',
  nickName: 'Stefino',
  email: 'stefano@gmail.com',
  imageProfile: 'assets/images/saverio.jpeg',
);

List<User> user = [
  currentUser,
];

// EXAMPLE MESSAGES IN CHAT SCREEN
List<Message> messages = [
  Message(
    sender: currentUser,
    time: '5:30 PM',
    text: 'Lorem Ipsum',
    isLiked: true,
    unread: true,
  ),
];
```

and also I defined other Consultant User class:

```
class ConsultantMessage {
  final Consultant sender;
  final String
      time; // Would usually be type DateTime or Firebase Timestamp in production apps
  final String text;
  final bool isLiked;
  final bool unread;

  ConsultantMessage({
    this.sender,
    this.time,
    this.text,
    this.isLiked,
    this.unread,
  });
}

class Consultant {
  final int id;
  final String consultantFirstName;
  final String consultantLastName;
  final String consultantNickName;
  final String consultantEmail;
  final String consultantImageProfile;
  final String consultantCategory;
  final String consultantDescription;
  final String consultantLikes;
  final String consultantReviews;
  final String consultantStars;
  final String consultantChatPrice;
  final String consultantVideoPrice;
  final String consultantExperience;
  final String consultantEmailPrice;
  final String consultantCallPrice;
  final String consultantChatText;
  final bool isOnline;
  final int value;
  final String dateTime;
  final String hours;
  final bool available;

  const Consultant(
      {this.hours,
      this.id,
      this.isOnline,
      this.consultantFirstName,
      this.consultantLastName,
      this.consultantNickName,
      this.consultantEmail,
      this.consultantImageProfile,
      this.consultantCategory,
      this.consultantDescription,
      this.consultantLikes,
      this.consultantReviews,
      this.consultantStars,
      this.consultantChatPrice,
      this.consultantVideoPrice,
      this.consultantExperience,
      this.consultantEmailPrice,
      this.consultantCallPrice,
      this.consultantChatText,
      this.value,
      this.dateTime,
      this.available});
}

final Consultant marco = Consultant(
    id: 1,
    consultantFirstName: 'Marco',
    consultantLastName: 'Marcello',
    consultantNickName: 'Tarot and Dreams',
    consultantEmail: 'marco@gmail.com',
    consultantCategory: 'Tarocchi',
    consultantDescription: 'Ciao a tutti sono Marco',
    consultantImageProfile: 'assets/images/rocco.jpg',
    consultantLikes: '2342',
    consultantReviews: '76245',
    consultantChatPrice: '3.90',
    consultantVideoPrice: '19.90',
    consultantEmailPrice: '15.90',
    consultantCallPrice: '2.60',
    consultantChatText: 'Ciao a tutti',
    consultantExperience: '12',
    isOnline: true,
    value: 3,
    available: true,
    dateTime: DateFormat('dd-MM-yyyy - kk:mm:ss').format(DateTime.now()));
 dateTime: DateFormat('dd-MM-yyyy - kk:mm:ss').format(DateTime.now()),

List<Consultant> consultant = [
  marco,
];

// EXAMPLE MESSAGES IN CHAT SCREEN
List<ConsultantMessage> consultantMessages = [
  ConsultantMessage(
    sender: marco,
    time: '5:30 PM',
    text: 'Hey, how\'s it going? What did you do today?',
    isLiked: true,
    unread: true,
  ),
```

Now I hard coded the chat screen:

```
class ChatScreen extends StatefulWidget {
  final Consultant consultant;

  const ChatScreen({Key key, this.consultant,}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  _ChatScreenState createState() => _ChatScreenState();
}

class _ChatScreenState extends State<ChatScreen> {
  _buildMessage(Message message, bool isMe) {
    final Container msg = Container(
      margin: isMe
          ? EdgeInsets.only(
        top: 8.0,
        bottom: 8.0,
        left: 55.0,
      )
          : EdgeInsets.only(
        top: 8.0,
        bottom: 8.0,
      ),
      padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 25.0, vertical: 15.0),
      width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width * 0.35,
      decoration: BoxDecoration(
        color: isMe ? Colors.orange.shade100 : Colors.purple.shade100,
        borderRadius: isMe
            ? BorderRadius.only(
            topLeft: Radius.circular(5),
            topRight: Radius.circular(20),
            bottomLeft: Radius.circular(5))
            : BorderRadius.only(
            topRight: Radius.circular(5),
            topLeft: Radius.circular(20),
            bottomRight: Radius.circular(5)),
      ),
      child: Column(
        crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
        children: <Widget>[
          Row(
            mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
            children: [
              isMe ? CircleAvatar(
                radius: 25,
                backgroundImage: AssetImage(currentUser.imageProfile),
              ):
              CircleAvatar(
                radius: 25,
                backgroundImage: AssetImage(widget.consultant.consultantImageProfile),
              ),
              SizedBox(width: 10,),
              Expanded(
                child: Text(
                  message.text,
                  style: TextStyle(
                    color: Colors.black87,
                    fontSize: 13.0,
                    fontWeight: FontWeight.w400,
                  ),
                ),
              ),
              SizedBox(width: 8,),
              Text(
                message.time,
                style: TextStyle(
                  color: Colors.black87,
                  fontSize: 11.0,
                  fontWeight: FontWeight.w400,
                ),
              ),
            ],
          ),
        ],
      ),
    );
    if (isMe) {
      return msg;
    }
    return Row(
      children: <Widget>[
        msg,
        IconButton(
          icon: message.isLiked
              ? Icon(Icons.favorite)
              : Icon(Icons.favorite_border),
          iconSize: 30.0,
          color: message.isLiked
              ? Theme.of(context).primaryColor
              : Colors.blueGrey,
          onPressed: () {},
        )
      ],
    );
  }

  _buildMessageComposer() {
    return Container(
      padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 8.0),
      height: 70.0,
      color: Colors.white,
      child: Row(
        children: <Widget>[
          IconButton(
            onPressed: () {},
            icon: Tooltip(
              message: 'Invia un immagine',
                child: Icon(Icons.photo)),
            iconSize: 25.0,
            color: Colors.purple,
          ),
          Expanded(
            child: TextField(
              textCapitalization: TextCapitalization.sentences,
              onChanged: (value) {},
              decoration: InputDecoration.collapsed(
                hintText: 'Invia un messaggio...',
              ),
            ),
          ),
          IconButton(
            icon: Icon(Icons.send),
            iconSize: 25.0,
            color: Colors.purple,
            onPressed: () {},
          ),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      backgroundColor: Colors.white,
      appBar: AppBar(
        backgroundColor: Colors.purple,
        title: Row(
          children: [
            Text(
              'Stai chattando con ',
              style: TextStyle(
                fontSize: 16,
                fontWeight: FontWeight.w300,
              ),
            ),
            Text(
              widget.consultant.consultantFirstName,
              style: TextStyle(
                fontSize: 16,
                fontWeight: FontWeight.w300,
              ),
            ),
            SizedBox(width: 5,),
            CircleAvatar(
              radius: 17,
              backgroundImage: AssetImage(widget.consultant.consultantImageProfile),
            ),
          ],
        ),
        elevation: 10,
        actions: <Widget>[
          IconButton(
            icon: Tooltip(
              message: 'Segnala la Chat',
                child: Icon(Icons.report)),
            iconSize: 25.0,
            color: Colors.white,
            onPressed: () {},
          ),
        ],
      ),
      body: GestureDetector(
        onTap: () => FocusScope.of(context).unfocus(),
        child: Column(
          children: <Widget>[
            Expanded(
              child: ListView.builder(
                reverse: true,
                padding: EdgeInsets.only(top: 15.0),
                itemCount: messages.length,
                itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) {
                    final Message message = messages[index];
                    final bool isMe = message.sender.id == currentUser.id;
                    return _buildMessage(message, isMe);
                },
              ),
            ),
            _buildMessageComposer(),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

I can get the currentUser message but I can't get get the Consultant User message.
Where am I doing wrong

Answer (score 1):

In your `ListView.builder` -> `itemCount: messages.length,` here you are using `messages` array from `class User`, and this array contains only one message that belongs to the currentUser, try to add more messages to this array. even if you have `consultantMessages`, you are not using with your list, as a solution you can do the following :

```
List<Message> messages = [
  Message(
    sender: currentUser,
    time: '5:30 PM',
    text: 'Lorem Ipsum',
    isLiked: true,
    unread: true,
  ),
  Message(
    sender: marco,
    time: '5:30 PM',
    text: 'Hey, how\'s it going? What did you do today?',
    isLiked: true,
    unread: true,
  ),
];
```

Comment: sure if I add more messages I get more message for this user, the problem is that I cant get messages from the other user.
The example you wrote doesnt work return error "The element type 'ConsultantMessage' can't be assigned to the list type 'Message'."

Comment: Yes it is ```Message``` not ```ConsultantMessage``` ( You have to keep one close from the two)

Comment: I understand you and I did what you suggested... the problem is that I can't display the Consultant Message I can display USER messages to theright side but the chat should display the Consultant message as sender

Comment: All the messages are from only one user (both with id 1) so inside you ```ListView``` this line ```final bool isMe = message.sender.id == currentUser.id;``` always true